# c++ iterate through list [and then manipulations of different iterators from the same class]

Tags: c++, list

Let's assume we have a class named `Student` and `data` is the list.

```
std::list<Student>::iterator<Student> it;
for(it = data.begin(); it != data.end(); ++it){
    std::cout<<(*it)->name;
    it->print();
}


   std::list<Student>::iterator<Student> it2;
for(it2 = data.begin(); it2 != data.end(); ++it2){
    std::cout<<(*it2)->name;
    it2->print();
}
```

What the `mult` represents when we take the addition (or multiplication) of the iterators that we got from two different lists. I mean what happens if we take the multiplication of `*it` and `*it2`

```
for(it = data.begin(); it != data.end(); ++it){

    Student mult = (*it) * (*it2);

   }
```

Can you give an example conceptually?

Comment: There's no way for us to say or even guess. You have to check the `operator*` overload for the `Student` class.

Comment: Well, what does the `Student Student::operator*(const Student&)` or `Student operator*(const Student&, const Student&)` do?

Comment: @zero_field If you'd taken the time to try to create a [mre], you'd discovered the `operator*` yourself.

Comment: _"when we take the addition (or multiplication) of the iterators"_ that's not what happens there.

Comment: _@zero_ BTW, shouldn't the result of a multiplication of `Student`s rather be `SquareStudent`s?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ  `int * int` => `squareint`? :-)

Comment: @Ted Well, the natural numbers aren't the same set as the set of students, no?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Probably not. The only thing I know about `Student` is that it has a `print` member function, a `name` member variable and an overload for `operator*`.

Comment: BTW, thanks. EVeryone.  It's a very simple question as I understand now.  I should have written a simple example to get the point, but now I understood.

Comment: I thought of asking a simple right question. But if you think, please go ahead and edit it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this compiles:

```
Student mult = (*it) * (*it2);
```

there is an `operator*` overload defined for `Student` - but it doesn't have anything to do with the iterators. The iterators are dereferenced (`*`) so you have two references to `Student`s being multiplied.

The most likely place to find the answer:

```
Student operator*(const Student&, const Student&) {
    // the answer to your question is in here
}
```